# How to remove check out option from WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, themes, e-commerce, shopping-cart

My website is an affiliate website and the products listed there are not owned by me. I just want to list affiliate products and the buy now link will be of the affiliates website. So, I don't want the check out option on my website. I want to know that how can I remove check out and shopping cart option from WooCommerce plugin?

Comment: Create external products.

Answer (score 2):

try this

Add the filter to your theme's functions.php file.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
```